# Advanced boot options shows only Vista but OS is XP. Was this a bad install of XP?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-vista, installation

I was researching a BSOD on a computer at work, and trying to go into safe mode.  At the advanced boot options screen the only OS choice was Vista, but the OS on this machine is XP.  When I select Vista it boots and is XP.  Also, there is no safe mode option, just Vista and diagnostics.  Did someone try to do an "upgrade" from Vista to XP instead of a complete reinstall?  That is my guess, but I am not sure.  Also, should I do another reinstall to correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This suggests that Windows XP is booting via the Windows Vista bootsector, which is most likely the consequence of using poorly configured (or outright broken) multi-boot software.

Windows XP is designed to be booted from the Windows XP bootsector and Windows Vista from the Windows Vista bootsector. If problems like this are happening the best thing to do is format the disk and start over with a new fresh installation of Windows.

Given that you'll be wiping the disk and installing afresh anyway, it might be worth upgrading to Windows7, since Windows XP has been moth-balled by Microsoft and Windows Vista isn't great.

Comment: Thanks! I figured a fresh install was the way to go.  Now to convince my higher-ups to shell out for Windows 7. :)